# Construction of hyperbola asymptotes problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line, geometric-construction

**Three points $A$, $B$, $C$ and a line $p$ (that does not pass through the said points) are given. Let $H$ be a hyperbola that passes through points $A$, $B$ and $C$, and the direction $p$ one of its asymptotes. Construct the line through the point $A$ that is perpendicular to the other asymptote of the hyperbola.**

If another point $D$ of the hyperbola $H$ was given, the solution would be relatively simple. By applying Pascal's theorem to the hexagon $AABCDP$, where $P$ is the infinitely far point of the asymptote $p$, tangent $t_1$ of
hyperbola $H$ at point $A$ is easily found. Analogously, by applying Pascal's theorem to the hexagon $ABCCDP$, we can easily find tangent $t_2$ to hyperbola $H$ at point $C$. Now, let $p \cap t_1 =S_1$ and $c_1=c(A, |AS_1|)$ (circle of radius $|AS_1|$ centered at $A$ ). Let $G_1$ denote the intersection $c_1 \cap t_1$. By the same logic, $p \cap t_2=S_2$ and $c_2=c(C, |CS_2|)$. Now $G_2=c_2 \cap t_2$.
$G_1G_2$ is the other asymptote of the hyperbola. Now the construction of the perpendicular from $A$ to $G_1G_2$ is trivial. However, point $D$ is **not** given. I am wondering if there is a way to construct point $D$ using the given points $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: If $p$ is the asymptote (not only parallel to it) then you can use Pascal's theorem by considering hexagon $AABCDPP'$, where $P'$ is the point at infinity on $P$ reached in the other direction (and line $PP'$ is $p$).

Comment: @intelligentipauca You mean hexagon AABCPP'? Right....Now I feel so dumb for looking for the 'missing point' to be able to apply Pascal's theorem, when it was here the whole time. Thank you sir!!!

Comment: Yes, of course I meant hexagon $AABCPP'$. Glad I was of help.